# nautilus theme problem in 12.04

Tags: 12.04, nautilus, themes

I have encountered a strange theme problem since I updated to 12.04 some days ago: Nautilus needs some extra treatment after every login in order to obey the theme. It concerns every user. After every login the theme in nautilus (and only in nautilus, no other program is concerned) is set to orange-grey standard theme. Following steps bring back the correct theme: In terminal I have to enter

```
nautilus -q
nautilus
```

now nautilus has its complete theme back, but now desktop doesn't present any files and the context menu is not working anymore. Again in terminal I have to enter

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons false
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons true
```

After this theme in nautilus and desktop both work fine ... until next login. I want to underline, that only nautilus has this problem.

I use compiz and cairodock and have a twinview configuration, using nvidia proprietary driver.

**My question: What can I do to avoid these annoying procedure?**

Edit: Meanwhile I think this happens because nautilus is started on logon to handle desktop before *gnome-settings-daemon* has done its work completely. So I tried to look in *gnome-session-properties* how and when nautilus is started, but there is no corresponding entry. How can I verify whether my presumption is right or not?