# Script to quit and restart nautilus doesn't work

Tags: 12.04, nautilus, scripts

As I pointed out in my question [nautilus theme problem in 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/q/254876/123686) I have to type 4 commands after every logon as workaround for a theming problem. Since I didn't find a real solution I decided to put the commands into a script and my plan ist to make this  script autostart once it works properly.
The commands are:

```
nautilus -q
nautilus -n &
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons false
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons true
```

And this is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
nautilus -q
pid0=$(pgrep 'nautilus')
while [ -n "$pid" ];
do
  pid=$(pgrep 'nautilus')
  sleep 0
done
nautilus -n
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons false
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons true
exit 0
```

I had to use the loop and testing since otherwise nautilus is restarted before it has finished to quit itself.
But my script never ends. While *pgrep nautilus* entered manually in a terminal doesn't return any value after *nautilus -q*, runing the script returns endless a pid so the script isn't executed.

**What is my mistake? Where does the pid come from when the command is run within the script?**

And how can I restart nautilus from within the script avoiding nautilus to block the script forever from further execution? The line *nautilus -n* starts nautilus and the script hangs from there on. Using *nautilus -n &* instetead makes the script run, but the follwing commands are executed before nautilus has completely started so they dont't work as intended, desktop settings are not applied.

Are there any other ideas to cope with this annoying command-typing at every logon?

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems here. Let's walk through your script.

1. You write `pid0=$(pgrep 'nautilus')`, but test the variable `$pid` (not `$pid0`) afterwards. I assume you meant to instead write

   ```
   pid=$(pgrep 'nautilus')
   ```
2. If I understand correctly, the intention of your loop is to stall execution of the script until `$pid` is empty, i.e., until `nautilus` has stopped running. Indeed, the command `nautilus -q` will send a running Nautilus application the signal to quit, but the command `nautilus -q` itself will already have succesfully terminated before the running Nautilus application has processed that signal and successfully terminated itself also. Thus, your idea of using a loop in order to wait for the Nautilus application to terminate is valid. However, that loop does not run indefinitely as you say. Run your script with `bash -x` in order to see what happens. For example, this script:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash -x
   nautilus -q
   pid=$(pgrep 'nautilus')
   while [ -n "$pid" ];
   do
     pid=$(pgrep 'nautilus')
     sleep 0
   done
   echo "Nautilus has stopped running!"
   ```

   ...when executed while a Nautilus application is running, gives me the following output:

   ```
   + nautilus -q
   ++ pgrep nautilus
   + pid=24602
   + '[' -n 24602 ']'
   ++ pgrep nautilus
   + pid=24602
   + sleep 0
   + '[' -n 24602 ']'
   ++ pgrep nautilus
   + pid=24602
   + sleep 0
   + '[' -n 24602 ']'
   ++ pgrep nautilus
   + pid=24602
   + sleep 0
   + '[' -n 24602 ']'
   ++ pgrep nautilus
   + pid=24602
   + sleep 0
   + '[' -n 24602 ']'
   ++ pgrep nautilus
   + pid=
   + sleep 0
   + '[' -n '' ']'
   + echo 'Nautilus has stopped running!'
   Nautilus has stopped running!
   ```

   As you see, the loop does not run indefinitely. In your case, the loop is never even entered in the first place, because of problem (1). To answer your question *Where does the pid come from when the command is run within the script?* -- The pid comes from the running Nautilus application. The reason that you do not see a pid when running `pgrep nautilus` after `nautilus -q` from the *Terminal* is simple: You're not fast enough. The time you take to type `pgrep nautilus` after you have run `nautilus -q` is plenty, and when you finally run that command from the terminal, the Nautilus application has already terminated long ago; thus you do not see a pid. You can check this by typing `nautilus -q; pgrep nautilus` (as a single command) in the terminal while a Nautilus application is running: You have a good chance of seeing a pid then.
3. Cosmetic: There is no point in `sleep 0`, and having `pid=$(pgrep 'nautilus')` twice in your script is a bit redundant. Start like this:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   nautilus -q
   while [ -n "$(pgrep nautilus)" ]
   do :
   done
   ```
4. The reason that your script does not end is another than the loop: It is the command `nautilus -n`. Since this command does not terminate (by itself), your script just hangs. So you *do* have to run it in the background using `nautilus -n &`. As there is no easy way to determine from the script whether Nautilus has "completely started" such that desktop settings will apply (that I know of... save for some ugly boilerplate code that will try to set and read a dummy desktop setting in a loop in order to check that), the easiest thing is probably to just set an appropriate waiting time that will work for you in practice, say, `sleep 2`.

**Summing up**, I expect the following to work for you:

```
#!/bin/bash

nautilus -q
while [ -n "$(pgrep nautilus)" ]
do :
done

nautilus -n &
sleep 2
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons false
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons true
```

Comment: One of the best answers in AU that had no up votes... remedied.